# BEM vs Global Resets

Tags: html, css, sass, tags, bem

I recently started using BEM for writing reusable CSS components. In the [BEM documentation](https://en.bem.info/methodology/faq/#can-i-use-a-css-reset) and other websites I found that global resets on tag elements are not encouraged for obvious reasons.

However when I look at source code of BEM based websites including the BEM documentation websites, I usually see p tags classless, meaning they do use resets or nested selectors to give them the proper font size or margin for instance.

Consequently, I am confused about what approach to follow now. In my reckoning, creating a `paragraph` class and attaching it to `p` tags would be the correct approach in this case. Further positioning could be resolved by implementing additional layout components to set the desired margins?

Any advice? Thanks in advance?

Comment: Indeed, it is sometimes necessary to disobey a doctrine. ;)

Comment: So in other words, it's okay to use global resets ? Isn't the whole point of BEM to create reusable standalone components ? Lol

Comment: You can declare your BEM components are reusable only in the context of a global reset. It's not that bad. That's what I do.

Comment: I believe the purpose of global resets are to set a consistent style baseline that the rest of the app can follow. As far as overwriting tags, I think it's ok if its down once at the top level in a single place and if you maintain the consistent semantic usage. For instance, reserve the use of `<p>` for paragraphs. Apart from that initial global reset to establish a global baseline, do not overwrite tags. Instead, use can use BEM to define styles specific to components. Reset & BEM are compatible. The reset is like tilling a field, and the BEM components are the crops you choose to grow in it.

Comment: Thanks you guys for the feedback. One more thing, would you also apply base margins such as to the <p> tag or create layout components to align them properly ?

Comment: Rich texts are an issue for BEM components. Personally I reset the margins and paddings for `<p>` tags. Then, I create a "not BEM component" named `rich-text` with cascades: `.rich-text p {/*margins and padding here*/}` etc. It's fine. But you have to remember that other components cannot be nested into this `rich-text` component.

Comment: Oh I see. Do you have any resources or further examples  for that technique you applying for rich texts? It seems a little messy compared to creating layout components as the BEM way would suggest.

Comment: Sorry, the only resource I have is from me but [in french](https://www.alsacreations.com/article/lire/1641-bonnes-pratiques-en-css-bem-et-oocss.html). A rich text cannot be BEM compliant. But rich texts are not a big deal, it's just the base of the Web. :) BEM is a good tool to layout a website, it is also an excellent tool to structure the appearance of a web application.

Comment: Thanks, I appreciate it still.

Answer (score 0):

My understanding is that a css reset is not required because essentially every block or element has a class on with a specificity set to 010. Therefore this overrides any css including the browsers own css file that only has a specificity set to 001 on the element.